# What's ctypes.c_ssize_t?

Tags: python-3.x, posix, ctypes

I am reading the python3 ctypes documentation and stumble [upon](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_ssize_t):

> ```
> class ctypes.c_ssize_t
> Represents the C ssize_t datatype.
> ```

I am surprised to read this, since `ssize_t` is not defined in C (but POSIX). Is the documentation inaccurate, and instead meant to say `ptrdiff_t` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Issue #6729](https://bugs.python.org/issue6729) (migrated to GitHub as [Issue #50978](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/50978)) raised awareness of the lack of `ctypes.c_ssize_t`, and a patch was added to remedy the missing type, so the answer to your question is no, `ptrdiff_t` was not intended.